# How to handle multiple elements with imagemagick cli?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

We need to put 'information bar's to thousands of image files. For like a week or so i'm trying to learn imagemagick but i just couldn't figure this many elements out so i wanted to ask for a help here.

I get the idea of '-/+append'ing elements and swapping between them but when it comes to 3x3 matrix cells and text/image mixings, i just can't do it. As an example, i can get the 3 rows appended and a column next to it but i can't get to the next step of 'appending 2 more rows together then put them as a column block again' because when i try, all those append gets right or bottom as a whole image.. Well, you will get the idea when you see my brief image below..

```
magick.exe -size 150x100 -gravity center caption:"txt2" caption:"txt3" caption:"txt4" \
 -append -size 94x294 xc:white -border 3 -swap 0,1 \
 +append outoutout.jpg
```

FYI, height/width of rows/columns are there just for example not important.. And here comes MSPaint skills:
[image: Final Output Idea]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create each section separately using parenthesis processing. Then if you want append them appropriately. Alternately, you can create a background image and compose ... -composite each image into its correct location.

Here is an example in ImageMagick using the second method.

Unix Syntax:

```
magick -size 400x400 xc:white \
\( barn.jpg -crop 400x200+0+0 +repage \) \
    -geometry +0+0 -compose over -composite \
\( -size 100x200 xc:white -shave 5x5 -bordercolor black -border 5 \) \
    -gravity northwest -geometry +0+200 -compose over -composite \
\( -size 100x200 -background white -gravity center -fill black \
    -font Candice label:"Text1\n\nText2\n\nText3" \) \
    -gravity northwest -geometry +100+200 -compose over -composite \
\( -size 100x200 -background skyblue -gravity center -fill red \
    -font Arial label:"First_line\n\n\nSecond_line" \) \
    -gravity northwest -geometry +300+200 -compose over -composite \
result.png
```

[image]

See for example:

[parenthesis processing](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#parenthesis)

[appending](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append_array)

[convert ... -composite](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#convert)

Comment: That is a great solution, thank you. With '-geometry', i will manage every element so it solves everything. Just 1 small quick question, is there any 'if clause' on imagemagick? For example 'if the main image(barn.jpg in your example)'s width<1000px, then resize to barn.jpg's width or just dont do anything.. Else do this command etc.. (This is not so important, i just want to see how more powerful imagemagick can be..)

Comment: There is no specific if command within a command line. However, with IM 7, you can do condition computations. Also there are flags for resizing and image if it is larger (or smaller) than some specified size. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry